# Проверить массив строк на вхождение в строку

Tags: java, алгоритм

Дан массив строк, например: ["молоко", "мама", "масло"], дана строка: "Я купил масло", нужно найти элемент(ы) массива, которые входят в строку, как лучше реализовать? Первое что приходит в голову:

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : str) {
   if (stroka.contains(s)) {
      result.add(s);
   }
}
return result;
```

может есть еще какой-то способ?

Comment: Если входная строка будет содержать текст: "На молокозаводе маслоделы ели мамалыгу", будут ли считаться вхождения указанных слов  `масло`, `мама`, `молоко`?

Comment: нет, нужно чтоб слово полностью совпадало (сделано через костыль, поэтому приходится работать с тем что есть)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно сравнивать отдельные слова, а не просто их вхождение во входную строку, то последнюю следует разбить на *слова*, исключив небуквенные символы, (опционально) привести все слова к единому регистру, собрать эти слова в `Set<String>` и затем отфильтровать список слов по условию их вхождения в данное множество:

```java
static void printWords(String stroka, List<String> str) {
    Set<String> words = Arrays.stream(stroka.split("\\P{L}+"))
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println(words);

    List<String> result = str.stream()
        .filter(words::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Для тестовых данных:

```java
printWords("Мама мыла раму, я купил масло.", Arrays.asList("мама", "масло", "молоко"));
```

Результат:

```
[масло, мама, купил, мыла, раму, я]
[мама, масло]
```

Можно решить это и без Stream API, используя обычный метод `List::retainAll`:

```java
static void printWordsNoStream(String stroka, List<String> str) {
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        stroka.toLowerCase().split("\\P{L}+")
    ));
    System.out.println(words);

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(str); // изменяемая копия str
    result.retainAll(words); // удаляем из result всё, что не входит в words
    System.out.println(result);
}
```